# Add 64 bit numbers in 32-bit windows

Tags: php

The following code:

```
$val = "209810563658809344";
echo sprintf('%0.0f', ($val - 1) + "<br />");     
echo sprintf('%0.0f', (bcsub($val, 1)) + "<br />");
```

In windows 32 bit outputs:

```
209810563658809344
209810563658809344
```

How can be made the subtraction to work properly?

Comment: You are aware of BC Math but then cast the output back to number...

Comment: sprint() with a mask of '%0.0f' is casting to float, just echo the result of your bc math

Comment: Alvaro, could you explain?  Not using printf just outputs 2.09810563659E+17

Comment: bcsub returns a string; so PHP will not automatically convert that to scientific notation unless you're doing something else - so show how you're trying to display it without the sprintf

Comment: And DON'T use `+` for concatenation: PHP !== javascript That's probably where your problem lies because addition will also force a cast to number

Comment: echo bcsub($val, 1) + "<br />";   outputs  2.09810563659E+17

Comment: See my previous note about `+`

Comment: Seems I was doing something wrong, bcsub($val, 1) works great and sprintf was not needed, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your sprint() masking and the use of `+` instead of `.` for concatenation are forcing a cast to numeric datatype

```
$val = "209810563658809344";
echo sprintf('%0.0f', ($val - 1)) . '<br />';     
echo bcsub($val, 1) . '<br />';
```

Comment: That works for that specific example, but not for 355325317306527744.

Comment: It works for 355325317306527744 too, please demonstrate otherwise!

Comment: Mark, are you using a 32 or 64 bit hosts? for windows 32 it does not work.

Comment: 32 bit PHP on windows 8: checking on 32-bit windows now

Comment: Right, seems I did something wrong while trying your code. Thanks (to everybody else too)!

Comment: Echoing a string should always echo a string, whether on a 32-bit or a 64-bit platform, and on Windows/*nix/Mac - works on a 32-bit XP box

Comment: you can also use `,` for concatening: `echo sprintf('%0.0f', ($val - 1)), '<br />', PHP_EOL;` (only in echo!)

Comment: `,` doesn't actually concatenate; it simply acts as a separator for multiple arguments.... in this case, arguments passed to echo

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the conversion to floating point and you'll be fine.

```
$val = "20981056365880934";
echo bcmul($val, 2, 0)." ≈ ".bcdiv($val, 2, 0)." × 2 + ".bcsub($val, 1, 0)." + 1";
```

Note the third scale parameter which allows you to control precision like `printf()`. See [the bc manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)

Comment: Seems I was doing something wrong, bcsub($val, 1) works great, thanks!